# typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') in xcode 14

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podfile, xcode14, react-native-permissions

I am getting above error while running build in Xcode 14. Have tried running yarn ios as well, but that also fails with "(in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')".
Have been through many threads from past 1 week, nothing seems to work for me.
I have tried formatting my Mac as well, still the same problem persists.
React native version - 0.65
If anyone has any leads, please let me know.
Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks!